# When is the composition of Lipschitz and Lp still Lp?

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, lipschitz-functions

I'm wondering in which situations the composition $f \circ v$ of a Lipschitz function $f$ and a $L^p$ function $v$ is still in $L^p$.

So one thing I came up with, is:

> **Claim:** Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be bounded, $g : \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ Lipschitz continuous with a root $v_0$ (i.e. $g(v_0)=0$). Then it holds
> $$ v \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m) \Rightarrow g \circ v \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m)$$
> **Proof:** As $\Omega$ is bounded the constant function $v_0$ is in $L^p(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m)$. Let $v \in L^p(\Omega, \mathbb{R}^m)$, then the Lipschitz property yields $$\Vert g(v(x)) \Vert_p^p = \Vert g(v(x)) - g(v_0) \Vert_p^p \leq C \Vert v(x) - v_0 \Vert_p^p$$ and therefore $$ \Vert g \circ v \Vert_{L^p} \leq C \Vert v - v_0 \Vert_{L^p} < \infty$$
> which proves the claim.

So my question is, do you know other similar results? And is it even possible to loose the assumptions in my claim? For instance, does the claim still hold, if the root assumption is removed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need the root assumption, and you actually never really used it in your proof (it only seems like you did). Think about why the last inequality holds. If you want $\Omega$ unbounded, then you should assume $g(0)=0$.

Comment: Ah I don't see it. Can you give me another hint?

Comment: Why did you introduce a root $v_0$? It serves no purpose

Comment: But my argument is $\Vert g(v) \Vert = \Vert g(v) - g(v_0) \Vert \leq C \Vert v -v_0 \Vert$. So the "magic" zero in the first inequality is where I use the root property of $v_0$.

Comment: Ah sorry, I was blinded by something else I'm looking for. So yes you are right, as I just wanted $\Vert g(v) \Vert < \infty$ I don't need the root $v_0$. As I can always do $\Vert g(v) \Vert  \leq \Vert g(v) - g(c) \Vert + \Vert g(c) \Vert < \infty $.

What I was thinking about, and this was not part of the question, is, if I can get a bound like $ \Vert g(v) \Vert \leq M \Vert v \Vert$. Do you for instance see, if this holds true?

Comment: @peek-a-boo Actually, for the unbounded case I don't think you need the assumption $g(0) = 0$. The way I see it right now, is that in the end you just need one $w \in L^p$ s.t. $g(w) \in L^p$ too. And then you can always do
$$\Vert g(v) \Vert \leq \Vert g(v) - g(w) \Vert + \Vert g(w) \Vert \leq C\Vert v -w \Vert + \Vert g(w) \Vert < \infty $$. Which, in the case of a bounded domain, is given for every constant function $w$.